# C Builder XE build time : ide versus command-line

Tags: command-line, time, build, ide, c++builder

I'm having a problem regarding C++ Builder XE3 : any project built from command-line (msbuild) takes about 50-60 % more time to complete, compared to the time spent building in the IDE.

Note : projects are using precompiled header.

Anybody have an idea on what could have this effect ?

Thanks in advance